# Viewing member in CMS gives fatal error: Allowed Memory Size Exhausted

Tags: error, fatal, memory

when trying to view specific members in the CMS, I'm getting this error all of a sudden with my new dreamhost server.  Anyone know how to fix this?  doesn't happen with all members just some it seems.

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 94371840 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /home/user/domain/admin_folder/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Model.php on line 610

Answer (score 0):

solved by having my hosting company help increasing php memory to 164mb.